# Android: OpenCV, Bag of words implementation on android

Tags: android, opencv

Is there a way to implement bag of words method for object classification
on android. I searched but i couldn't find any bag of words related
classes, like the ones that are included in the opencv c++ library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you look for it? I just had a look at OpenCV4Android-2.4.4 (which is not even the latest), and it appears in `sdk/native/jni/include/features2d/features2d.hpp`, with the name `BOWTrainer`.

The documentation is available [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/object_categorization.html).